# Why is it re-rendered to the previous state when input focus is released?

Tags: reactjs

I'm asking a question because I have no idea why. Why is it re-rendered to the previous state when input focus is released?
Here is the test code.

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const items = ["터미널", "미나리", "터보"];
function App() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

  const changeInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setUserInput(value);
    setKeyword(value);
  };

  const debounceFunction = (callback, delay) => {
    let timer;
    return (args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => callback(args), delay);
    };
  };

  const filtering = () => {
    items.filter((item) => item === keyword);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("call");
    console.log("userInput", userInput);
    console.log("keyword", keyword);
    debounceFunction(filtering, 500);
  }, [userInput]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <input value={userInput} onChange={changeInput}  autoFocus={true}/>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

A video recording of the phenomenon is also attached. Can you tell me what I did wrong?
You can view the video by following the link.
https://monii0312.notion.site/d938b086013541afa222a501bd5e5fcf?pvs=4

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code in my browser it worked fine. I suggest you try in a different browser or re-run the code with `npm run` and try again.

There might be some glitch.